# Ionic 4 Equivalent To IonicPage

Tags: typescript, ionic4

I'm trying to convert an Ionic 3 app to Ionic 4.

Can anyone tell me how I would convert IonicPage to its Ionic 4 equivalent?

I've done a lot of searching, but there doesn't seem to be many answers out there for this particular conversion.

Comment: have you checked the migration guide from the ionic? if not checkout this link - https://ionicframework.com/docs/reference/migration - it will help you to understand what steps required to convert.

Comment: Thanks @abhay jani. Not sure why that page has never come up in any searches I've done for Ionic 3 to 4 migration, but it's just what I've been looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If you have worked on angular 7+ you ll find it very easy.

It is very simple.
Html scss and ts code remains partial.

Step 1:
Welcome to ionic 4+ , you no longer create provider. We use something called as service.
ionic generate page contact
Creates contact page.
Than copy things from ionic 3 in 4.
Ts file copy imports, contructor and rest of the code.

There might be compatibility issues . But there are solutions for every problem.

Step 2:
Create service using
ionic generate service api
Copy provider code there.

Step 3: Fix any errors.

Step 4:
Build and run.